# Unity Ads "Advertisement does not contain definition for IsReady"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to implement unity ads into my game, but it throws the error `Assets/Scripts/UnityAds.cs(23,28): error CS0117: 'Advertisement' does not contain a definition for 'IsReady'` and `Assets/Scripts/UnityAds.cs(18,23): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Show' takes 0 arguments`

Here's the code of `UnityAds.cs`:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Advertisements;

public class UnityAds : MonoBehaviour
{

  public string GooglePlay_ID = "#######";
  public string placementID = "standardBanner";
  public bool TestMode = true;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Advertisement.Initialize(GooglePlay_ID, TestMode);
        StartCoroutine(ShowBannerWhenReady());
        Advertisement.Show();
    }


    IEnumerator ShowBannerWhenReady(){
      while(!Advertisement.IsReady(placementID)){
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);
      }
      Advertisement.Banner.SetPosition(BannerPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER);
      Advertisement.Banner.Show(placementID);


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
}
```

Any idea what could be causing this issue? I've already updated to the most recent version of UnityAds(And yes, I have the google play Id correct, I just didn't want to share that publicly

Comment: It's removed in SDK versions 4.0 and up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Window-> Package Manager -> in Project
2. Find the **Advertisement Package** and click **"Remove"**
3. Go to "Packages: Unity Registry" in Package Manager
4. find **Advertisement Package** and **install (you'll get V3.7.5)**
5. **restart Unity**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You can use SDK version 3.75 . It worked for me. for the second error remove Advertisement.Show() from void Start function.

Comment: Just because they have removed a function in the most recent version of the SDK it doesn't mean that you have to use an older version.

Comment: @MatterGoal how else are we supposed to check if an advertisement is ready before playing an ad in unity, since they removed this in the latest release?

Comment: @Jackhammer you have events to verify when the ads is loaded. OnUnityAdsAdLoaded <--- when you get this callback called, the Ads is ready. Save a flag at true or do any other simple trick to save this state...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but with unity cloud build, updating from 2019.4 to 2021.3.

Solution:

- Open PlayerSetting
- select services -> Ads
- turn on ads
- update version 3.75 -> 4.2

There is probably an error in cloud build where they use the most recent version instead of the one selected in the project.

[image]

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32378662)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you already saw, that Google asks you to update UnityAds to 4.0.1. In that case, you can't downgrade to 3.7.5. I found a solution for it. As I understood, new versions of UnityAds don't use IsReady();. So one thing for you to do is to correct your code like that:

Before:

```
if (Advertisement.IsReady)
        {
            Advertisement.Show("NameOfYourPlacement");
        }
```

After:

```
Advertisement.Show("NameOfYourPlacement");
```

I hope it helped for you, have a nice day!